# Add v-model dynamically to inputs dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dynamic table in my `vue` app that have inputs in the rows. The rows are added when the user clicks add row button. So I need to add v-model dynamically. My table looks like:

```
<table class="stripped centered">
        <tbody class="body-rows">
          <tr v-for="(row, index) in tableRows" :key="JSON.stringify(row)">
              <td colspan="8">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td><a @click.prevent="deleteRow(index)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-3 white-text"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i></a></td>
                    <td v-if="isCurrentSub"><input v-model ="inputData[row][sub_item_no-row]" class="item-no" type="number" step="0.001" placeholder="Item no"></td>
                    <td v-else><input v-model ="inputData[row][item_no-row]" class="item-no" type="number" step="0.001" placeholder="Item no"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>          
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

And in my script:

```
    return{
      currentRows: 0,
      tableRows: [],
      inputData: [],
      isCurrentSub: false,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    addRow(isSUb){
      this.currentRows++
      this.tableRows.push(this.currentRows)
      var tempObj = {}

      if(isSUb){
        this.isCurrentSub = true
        tempObj['sub_item_no-'+this.currentRows] = null

      }

      else{
        tempObj['item_no-'+this.currentRows] = null

      }

      this.inputData.push(tempObj)
      console.log(this.inputData[1]);

    },
```

As you see in the script above I have an array of objects. The objects include variables in which I want to store the values of the user input in each row. I tried to do this by doing:

```
<td v-if="isCurrentSub"><input v-model ="inputData[row][sub_item_no-row]" class="item-no" type="number" step="0.001" placeholder="Item no"></td>
<td v-else><input v-model ="inputData[row][item_no-row]" class="item-no" type="number" step="0.001" placeholder="Item no"></td>
```

I create two different inputs based on if the button clicked is Add Row or Add Sub. Both have different `v-model` values. But when I try this I get the following error:

```
property or method "item_no" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

I have a feeling that the approach I am taking is not right. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: @palaѕн you are right. It was too much unnecessary code. I have made an edit. Thank you.